# DataGridView Auto-calculate cells In Vb

Tags: vb.net

I want to multiply two columns of a `datagridview` and show the product in Column 3 of the same `datagridview`.

Example

```
Column1 - Column2 - Column3

12         2        24

15         2        30
```

Here is my Code

```
    Private Sub Table1DataGridView1_CellContentClick(sender As Object, e As DataGridViewCellEventArgs) Handles Table1DataGridView1.CellValidated
    Try
        Dim iCell1 As Integer
        Dim icell2 As Integer
        Dim icellResult As Integer
        iCell1 = Table1DataGridView1.CurrentRow.Cells(1).Value
        icell2 = Table1DataGridView1.CurrentRow.Cells(2).Value
        If String.IsNullOrEmpty(iCell1) OrElse String.IsNullOrEmpty(icell2) Then Exit Sub
        If Not IsNumeric(iCell1) OrElse Not IsNumeric(icell2) Then Exit Sub
        icellResult = CDbl(iCell1) * CDbl(icell2)
        Table1DataGridView1.CurrentRow.Cells(3).Value = icellResult
    Catch ex As Exception
        MessageBox.Show(ex.ToString)
    End Try
End Sub
```

It works but a new row is added afterwards. So please help.

Answer (score 0):

An elegant way is to use Databinding (the bread and butter method with datagridviews):

We create a new class, I call MultiplyPair. This class basically has to changable properties, `Value1` and `Value2`.
It also has a third, readonly property called `Product`.
Whenever `Value1` or `Value2` changes, we notify any bindingsource that also the product has changed (by implementing INotifyPropertyChanged).

This has several advantages:

- You avoid many quirks of the DGV that may arise during manual edits
- It's a great way to learn to use databinding (I'm just beginning myself to use the concept thoroughly and it's amazing)
- It's easily adaptable: Want also the product, sum and quotient? Just add properties and simple notifications.
- You have a clear structure, so other people can understand your code.
- You can reuse the whole logic, just bind another datagridview to the same bindinglist and you can display and change the information at multiple locations, with hardly any code.

To use the class we create a Bindinglist(Of MultiplyPair) and bind this list to the datagridview. Then we just ass values to the list and the datagridview is populated automatically. You can even change the values in the Datagridview and the product is automatically updated.

```
Public Class Form1
    Private WithEvents Values As New System.ComponentModel.BindingList(Of MultiplyPair) 'This holds one object for every line in the DGV

    Private Sub Form1_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
        Values = New System.ComponentModel.BindingList(Of MultiplyPair) 'Initialize the list
        DataGridView1.AllowUserToAddRows = False 'Disallow new rows, as per your question
        DataGridView1.DataSource = Values 'Bind the list to the datagridview
        'Add two example lines
        Values.Add(New MultiplyPair With {.Value1 = 2, .Value2 = 12})
        Values.Add(New MultiplyPair With {.Value1 = 15, .Value2 = 2})
    End Sub
End Class

Public Class MultiplyPair
   Implements System.ComponentModel.INotifyPropertyChanged
    'The first value
    Private _Value1 As Double
    Public Property Value1
        Get
            Return _Value1
        End Get
        Set(value)
            _Value1 = value
            'Notify not only that Value1 has changed, but also that the Product has changed
            Notify("Value1")
            Notify("Product")
        End Set
    End Property
    'Same as above
    Private _Value2 As Double
    Public Property Value2
        Get
            Return _Value2
        End Get
        Set(value)
            _Value2 = value
            Notify("Value2")
            Notify("Product")
        End Set
    End Property
    'This will show the product of Value1 and Value2 whenever asked
    Public ReadOnly Property Product
        Get
            Return Value1 * Value2
        End Get
    End Property

    'Helper sub to raise the PropertyChanged event with the given Propertyname
    Private Sub Notify(name As String)
        RaiseEvent PropertyChanged(Me, New System.ComponentModel.PropertyChangedEventArgs(name))
    End Sub

    'INotifyPropertyChanged implementation
    Public Event PropertyChanged(sender As Object, e As System.ComponentModel.PropertyChangedEventArgs) Implements System.ComponentModel.INotifyPropertyChanged.PropertyChanged
End Class
```

Edit: To avoid additional rows, set the `AllowUsersToAddRows` property of the Datagridview to false.